# html content doesn't update when using a smartadmin template

Tags: html, css, xampp

hi i'm working with a smartadmin template and i'm having problems when i try to modify the content of a tag, example:

example.html

```
<header>
  <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> </span>
       <h2>TITLE A </h2>            
</header>
```

if i try to change TITLE A for TITLE B it dont work, but if i save the page as example2.html it works it shows TITLE B, but i dont want to be creating a .html file everytime i want to change the title of the header of a form, i dont know too much about CSS or html and i can't post the cSS code since is paid html template and the css file is too large, my doubt is what could be the source of this problem, because everything in the page can be modified except the headers of the forms, adn if i create a new page like example2.html works fine but is tedious having to create a new page for just changing a line of html code. i'm using xampp

Comment: I dont't know smartadmin but i don't think you'll find answers with these tag, it look more that a programming issue that HTML/CSS issue

Comment: So you want to change the text for the header without refreshing the page or moving to a new page? You will need javascript for that.

Comment: @KyleT no is not that, i want to change the text without having to create a whole new page with the same content, i can't change the text at all! if i modify the .html page in any text editor and reload or refresh the page it have the same text

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and tried to solve this in many ways without success.
I found out that this mechanism uses like a memory to build objects. If an object is already in its own memory, it is not created fully again, some information are taken from this memory, and unfortunatelly the title is one of them. 
Each object is referenced by an ID. So the solution to my problem, instead of create a new HTML file, was change this ID dynamically using the date.
I created something that every time someone opens the file, the text CURRENT_DATE is replaced by the date.

```
<div class="jarviswidget" id="widget-id-CURRENT_DATE">
    <header>
        <h2>Title</h2>                           
    </header>
```